# Can not add FBSDKLoginKit to the Pod in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, swift4

I would like to add Facebook login functionality to the IOS (Swift) project.

I tried to proceed with "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1?locale=en_US" but I got stuck at the beginning.

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
$ pod init
$ pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

Moved to the project folder and the first line and the second line were executed successfully and the Podfile was created.

However, an error occurred on line 3.

> > [!] Unknown command: `FBSDKLoginKit`
> >
> > Did you mean: init?

I tried searching on the internet but I could not fix it.

Plz Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the step 3 carefully in doc's of Facebook.

Its adding pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' to your podfile not for typing in terminal.

Locate the podfile in Xcode project directory. Paste pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' inside.

[image]